# When trying to link word document to Excel, system hangs

Tags: microsoft-excel, ole

I'm trying to build an excel document that pulls in images and word documents into it from other files. Sometimes when I use the insert -> object function it works right, but other times it strangely hangs up with an error messages similar to this after a few minutes

"Microsoft application is trying to complete an OLE [task or something like that.]"

any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version (e.g. 2007, 2010) of Microsoft Office software involved and the operating system.